# Prevent XeTeX infinite loop

Tags: xetex, compiling, unicode-math

When compiling the following using XeTeX it just goes into an infinite loop and does not even give an error. Removing the `unicode-math` package solves the problem, but I want to use unicode-math. Renaming `nfeq` also solves the problem, but how do I know which identifiers are not compatible with packages in general? It took me a long time to narrow down the problem to this single macro, because I already had a huge document and wanted to use unicode-math. Thus my question is whether there is a way to quickly determine what are the unavailable identifiers and also whether there is a better way of defining macros that would prevent the problem from occurring in the first place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\def\feq{=}
\def\nfeq{\not\feq}
$\nfeq$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which LaTeX installation and OS are you using? I have no problem using TeX Live 2015, on Linux.

Comment: @daleif: Oh. I'm using Windows 7 and MikTeX 2.9.

Comment: Same setup here but I get the correct (in fact bad looking) result. Please delete your auxiliary files and compile again. Have a look, if all your packages are up to date.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Deleted all auxiliary files but it still doesn't work. Sorry it's taking a long time to update packages...

Comment: @user21820 well, as we can't reproduce this for now, updating everything and rebuilding the XeLaTeX-format would be a first thing to do. Let's try to get on the same status quo. Can't help you right now as I can't see the issue.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Something failed for some reason and now TeXworks cannot run, complaining that there is no ATL100.DLL...

Comment: Sorry to hear that. But this is not about TeX. See here http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-networking/unable-to-access-internet-and-getting-an-atl100dll/197d2b9c-2990-4ece-a565-5a8308bf4d8f?auth=1 for example.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Not only TeXworks but the MiKTeX Package Updater couldn't run.. I finally got them to run (by copying the old DLLs from the windows restore backup folder) and after updating unicode-math it no longer goes into an infinite loop. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been solved by updating the distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the `unicode-math` package I was using was an old one (0.7e) and the new version (0.7f) does not have the problem... Also, in case anyone gets into trouble with the package updating and both TeXworks and the package updater cannot run (they complain of missing DLLs), I solved it by copying the old DLLs (I'm on Windows so I could retrieve them via: Right-click on the folder MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin > restore previous versions > Right-click on a previous version > Open.)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have to check if your desired commands are already defind:

```
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\show\feq
\show\nfeq
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

The `.log` shows:

```
> \feq=undefined.
l.12 \show\feq


> \nfeq=undefined.
l.13 \show\nfeq
```

So there should be no problem in using those.

If they were already defined by some package, you would have to do `\renewcommand*{\feq}{=}` in order to get it overwritten. Better approach is always to do `\newcommand*{\myfeq}{=}`. If you are not so sure, if other packages in future will have this command, you could do `\providecommand*{\feq}{=}` which will only define this, if not yet existing.

As you are getting an infinite loop right now, you are having one of your commands defined already (not reproducible as daleif already said). You could either delete its definition by `\let\feq\relax` or rename it with `\let\feq\oldfeq` if you need to use that in some other case.

Finally, you should first look into the documentation of `unicode-math` in order to find your desired symbols which happen to be `\equal` (or just `=`) and `\ne`.

```
    % arara: xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
    \[A=B\ne C\equal D\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know I already have those symbols. Originally the symbol I defined was more complicated but I pared it down to the bare minimum needed to trigger the problem. I just tried `\show` as you said but both are shown to be `undefined`. `\newcommand` also fails to trigger an error but causes an infinite loop still. As before, using something other than `\nfeq` works.

Comment: @user21820 Do you have deleted the `.aux` file?